# Weird line 1px appearing on 3d spin transition cube CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue in chrome with a css3 transform rotate transition. The transition is working fine but just after it finishes the letters P and the letter F show a weird rendering, if you pay attention you will see a strange blurry line.

The bug isn't still there if you remove the transition as well.

You can see it happening here:

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.container .cube-container {
  perspective: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container .cube-container .cube {
  transition: transform 2s ease-in;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.container .cube-container .cube.cube1 {
  animation: horizontal-spin 5s ease-in-out;
}
.container .cube-container .cube.cube2 {
  animation: vertical-spin 5s infinite linear;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.front {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.front {
  background: #ff66cc;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.back {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: translateZ(-200px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.back {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.top {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-200px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.top {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-200px);
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.bottom {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(200px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.bottom {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(200px);
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.left {
  background: #ff66cc;
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-200px);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.left {
  background: black;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.right {
  background: black;
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(200px);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.container .cube-container .cube .box.box2.right {
  background: #c976e0;
}
@keyframes horizontal-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes vertical-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube cube1">
      <div class="box box1 front"> <div class="span2"><svg >
    <image xlink:href="https://www.matteogiordano.info/formy-prj.svg"  width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg></div>
  
</div>
      <div class="box box1 right">
        
        
         <div class="span2"><svg >
    <image xlink:href="https://www.matteogiordano.info/formy-f5.svg"  width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg></div>
        
      </div>
     
      <div class="box box1 left">
        
        
        <div class="span2">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #ff7dbe;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect width="300" height="300"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M250.88,106.87c-44.05,0-88.1,0-134.32,0,0,54.83,0,108.97,0,164.45-26.76,0-51.38,0-77.6,0,0-80.21,0-160.06,0-242.46,11.48,0,22.81,0,34.13,0,37.23,.03,74.47-.58,111.67,.28,41.05,.95,72.8,32.95,76.05,75.01,3.04,39.45-25.25,76.79-64.47,83.48-13.14,2.24-26.92,2.76-40.21,1.69-21.03-1.69-35.4-18.51-35.31-38.73,.09-21.35,15.08-37.82,37.21-38.7,24.35-.97,48.77-.32,73.16-.37,6.82-.01,13.21,0,20.03,0-.26-1.55-.08-3.11-.33-4.66Z"/>
</svg>
  
          
          
        
          
          
</div>
        
        
      </div>
      <div class="box box1 back">
        
        
        
        <div class="span2"><svg >
    <image xlink:href="https://www.matteogiordano.info/formy-d.svg"  width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg></div>
        
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--div class="cube cube2">
      <div class="box box2 front">Front</div>
      <div class="box box2 back">Back</div>
      <div class="box box2 top">Top</div>
      <div class="box box2 bottom">Bottom</div>
      <div class="box box2 left">Left</div>
      <div class="box box2 right">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```